# Object discriminated union types are merged when using fallback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am defining an array that needs to accept types of `string`, and `object`.  The `object` types must contain two properties: `name` and `value`.  `value` must be another object, containing an arbitrary set of `key: value` pairs.

I am trying to define some of the `object` types using a discriminated union, so that the properties of `value` for some specific `name` are known.  However, there always needs to remain a fallback so that when `name` is not a known string literal, `value` can still be any arbitrary set.

Here is what I'm working with so far:

```js
interface IFallbackDef {
    name: string;
    value: object;
}
type ValueDef<TName extends string = string, TOptions extends object = {}> = {
    name: TName;
    value: TOptions;
};
type Merged<TValueDef extends ValueDef> = (string | TValueDef | IFallbackDef)[];


interface ITest1Options {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}
interface ITest2Options {
    baz: string;
    qux: string;
}

const test: Merged<
    | ValueDef<'test1', ITest1Options>
    | ValueDef<'test2', ITest2Options>
> = [
    'asdf',
    {
        name: 'test1',
        value: {
            foo: 'asdjfkl',
            bar: 'asdf',

            /**
             * Intellisense shows both sets of properties,
             * and typescript allows them all, too
             */
            qux: 'asdfkljsdg' // This should be an error
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'test2',
        value: {
            baz: 'blah',
            qux: 'test',

            /**
             * Intellisense shows both sets of properties,
             * and typescript allows them all, too
             */
            foo: 'salfdj' // This should be an error
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'asdf',
        value: {
            /**
             * Intellisense shows both sets of properties,
             * should show none.
             */
        },
    },
]
```

The issue I have is that when I include `IFallbackDef` in the union, all of the types for the various `value` properties merge.  If I exclude `IFallbackDef`, the union works correctly, but the last index of the `test` array will be an error, because `name: 'asdf'` is unknown.

I assume that because `IFallbackDef` uses base types, and the shape is the same as `IValueDef`, it is merging the types... ?  At the moment, I'm kind of at a loss for how to make this work properly.  A fresh set of eyes would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand out the Merged type you end up with a type like:

```
(
    | string
    | { name: "test1", value: { foo: string, bar: string } }
    | { name: "test2", value: { baz: string, qux: string } }
    | { name: string, value: object }
)[]
```

The problem is that that isn't a discriminated union because of the `| { name: string, value: object }`.  That line breaks discriminated union checking because `string` is a match for both `'test1'` and `'test2'`, so TypeScript cannot discriminate.

You need to remove that line (e.g., remove `IFallbackDef` as you suggested) to get discriminated unions working.  Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a workaround that will let you achieve the goal of having things with a specific key type be of a specific value type, but then having things without one of those specific key types be of a different value type.

Depending on your constraints, one option would be to use a different key for the fallback.  For example:

```
interface IFallbackDef {
    not-name: string;
    value: object;
}
```

This will allow for discriminated union type checking of the objects with a name key separate from objects with a not-name key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option.  This is an effort to add, if not type safety, then type hinting to a public plugin API, which is designed in JS, and is already used extensively... and most of the plugins using it do not provide types for the `value` that pertains to their entry.  I think that to do what I'm trying to do, the entire API would need to be redesigned, and that's not my call.  It does need it, though.  Appreciate the help

Comment: See my answer for how to specify the fallback without needing a different key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=54&ssc=16&pln=54&pc=20#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-n4kx6U3AnMhan8EDxQshsFhCy4yxAmIOcAEwJC2+64zG58I6QyfRGA1g5KbeGdkDGY4Fc5m89JxFhHMhcChO90oPWoHO0cJVK2nVaPbafWL1a+Qy6pO+IaknAFI+rgWBwLmwZAbS9J2mKUZOrGCZLsIKaoGmGZZpEKAcPmRaXqW5ZZlWMi1vWjbNhwv4wXQHZdj2HB9sAA5DiO3a5uOk5YNOs5Icmi78e6Xp2hw2AwI4ci7vuh7Hnhp7npe14gLe96PgKL6WnOn6+pGNHuv+7CAUB8aJkJ86ppAWHZrh+EuCA0jIHWDbQFRqH0Auj76cgmnUNcQA)

I use `Exclude<string, 'test1'|'test2'>` to denote "all strings other than test1 and test2".

I'm not sure if it's possible to make it error when an extra property is specified.

Comment: Eh, same problem, really.  I can live with it not throwing an error; I kind of expected it not to anyway, since it still needs to accept a `value` object that has some unknown set of properties.  At the very least, I am hoping to get accurate intellisense, because currently it seems to act as a simple union, merging all possible properties of `value` across the different interfaces.  Thank you, though